# Can this device be made by anyone now?

Tags: manufacturing

In reference to the patent: [CA2366687C](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2366687C)

Answer (score 1):

A) That would be a legal opinion that would be best asked - in that form - to a patent attorney.

B) To answer the underlying question, of how do **I** find out whether a patent is expired?

- There are several things to take into consideration - what patent term applies to the patent, whether there were extensions, whether the patent was allowed to lapse early (and isn't in a grace period), etc.
- Patent Baristas has a [good article](http://www.patentbaristas.com/archives/2007/07/26/how-can-you-tell-if-a-patent-has-truly-expired/) helping you step through the process.
- PatentBytes also has a good [Patent 101 article](http://patentbytes.com/patents-101-how-to-figure-out-if-a-patent-has-expired/) introducing the steps necessary to begin determining if the patent is still in force.
- Further, the patent also may be at some point ruled invalid - which is an even more complicated topic best researched in depth, and discussed with an experienced patent attorney.

C) Also note the associated patents issued in the US, EU, etc. listed in the top right of the Google patent listing you linked to.

Answer (score 0):

No. Or at least, not without risking getting sued.

This patent appears to be granted and currently in force in Canada (according to [CIPO](http://brevets-patents.ic.gc.ca/opic-cipo/cpd/eng/patent/2366687/summary.html#tabs1_5), with all renewal fees up to date.

Comment: Can you expand on how do you find out or know if the patent is open?